# StatusCallback not called after requestNewReadPermissions then requestNewPublishPermissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an Android App that integrates with Facebook. I would like to:

1. Let the user login with Facebook
2. Get the user's email address on Facebook (could be a [proxied email address](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/355/), which is fine)
3. Post to the user's wall/timeline on his/her behalf

Technically, that would be to:

1. Authenticate the user
2. Request the [`email` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)
3. Request the [`publish_stream` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)

#### 1. Authenticate the user

I called [`Session.openActiveSession()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#openActiveSession(Activity,%20boolean,%20StatusCallback)) with a [`Session.StatusCallback`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.StatusCallback) (I already checked that there is no active opened session beforehand):

```
final Session.StatusCallback sessionStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // If there is an exception...
        if(exception != null)
        {
            // Handle fail case here.
            return;
        }

        // If session is just opened...
        if(state == SessionState.OPENED)
        {
            // Handle success case here.
            return;
        }
    };
};

// Start Facebook Login.
Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, sessionStatusCallback);
```

My callback is called after successful login. So far so good.

#### 2. Request the [`email` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)

This is my status callback:

```
new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // If there is an exception...
        if(exception != null)
        {
            // Handle fail case here.
            return;
        }
        
        // If token is just updated...
        if(state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)
        {
            // Handle success case here.
            return;
        }
    };
};
```

I request the permission with [`Session.requestNewReadPermissions()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#requestNewReadPermissions(NewPermissionsRequest)):

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
final static String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ = {"email"};
final List<String> permissionList = Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);

// If all required permissions are available...
if(session.getPermissions().containsAll(permissionList))
{
    // Handle success case here.
    return;
}

// Request permissions.
session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, permissionList));
```

My callback is called after permission is granted. So far so good.

#### 3. Request the [`publish_stream` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)

This is my status callback:

```
new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // If there is an exception...
        if(exception != null)
        {
            // Handle fail case here.
            return;
        }
        
        // If token is just updated...
        if(state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)
        {
            // Handle success case here.
            return;
        }
    };
};
```

I request the permission with [`Session.requestNewPublishPermissions()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#requestNewPublishPermissions(NewPermissionsRequest)):

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
final static String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_PUBLISH = {"publish_stream"};
final List<String> permissionList = Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_PUBLISH);

// If all required permissions are available...
if(session.getPermissions().containsAll(permissionList))
{
    // Handle success case here.
    return;
}

// Request permissions.
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, permissionList));
```

This time, my callback is **not** called after permission is granted.

#### Investigation

Upon further investigation, I found that my callback is triggered by [`com.facebook.Session#postStateChange(SessionState, SessionState, Exception)`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/sdk-version-3.0/facebook/src/com/facebook/Session.java#L1160-1164):

```
void postStateChange(final SessionState oldState, final SessionState newState, final Exception exception) {
    if (oldState == newState && exception == null) {
        return;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Since `oldState` and `newState` are equal (both being [`SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/SessionState#OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED), my callback is not called.

#### Question

How can I receive any notification after permission is granted for the 2nd time? Am I supposed to [`close()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#close()) the session and [re-open it from cache](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#openActiveSessionFromCache(Context))?

#### Additional info

My Facebook Android SDK 3.0 is download from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.zip), which is stated in Facebook's [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug.

*[edit: As Guy points out in comments, this was fixed in 3.0.1, so this workaround is no longer necessary]*

The workaround you mention is basically correct, though you do not need to call close.  If you are using the single active session, before calling requestNewPublishPermissions() just call:

```
Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(myContext);
```

If you are using multiple sessions, you need to initialize a new Session with the TokenCachingStrategy, verify it is in the CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED state, and call openForRead(null);

After doing one of these, requestNewPublishPermissions() should call your notification once it completes.

Comment: I've put together a couple of articles ([here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-opening-session.html) and [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-requesting.html)) which take @rightparen's workaround intro consideration and fully explain getting started opening a Facebook session and requesting additional permissions.

Comment: In the latest FB SDK 3.0.1 this does not happen anymore, and there is no longer a need to call `openActiveSessionFromCache`

Comment: I have the latest 3.0.1 and I even tried adding this line, and nothing. I don't get the call back, but If I check the permission afterwards it works.Drives me insane

Comment: Hey, I am getting similar issue. Can you please tell me where can i exactly put the line of code ? There is no method `requestNewPublishPermissions()` used in my code. So i am bit confused. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Working code based on [rightparen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14046916/1402846)

Before requesting permission for the 2nd time (i.e. before [`Session.requestNewPublishPermissions()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#requestNewPublishPermissions(NewPermissionsRequest))), do this:

```
// Re-initialize Facebook session.
session.removeCallback(sessionStatusCallback);          // Remove callback from old session.
session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(context);  // Create new session by re-opening from cache.
session.addCallback(sessionStatusCallback);             // Add callback to new session.
```

Code is still based on Facebook Android SDK 3.0, as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I ran into was that my requestCode for the `NewPermissionRequest` was not being set to the same requestCode that I used to open my `Session` for Read with, thereby my `Session.StatusCallback` was never being invoked when the new permissions have been granted.

For instance, in my `onActivityResult` I have a check for the requestCode and delegate the call accordingly because I have other stuff coming in to this method.

```
public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if(session != null) {
            session.onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }       
}
```

I then opened my `Session` with the following code :

```
        Session.getActiveSession().openForRead(
            new Session.OpenRequest(activity).
                setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK).
                setRequestCode(FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE).
                setPermissions(MY_READ_PERMISSIONS));
```

I then forgot to use the same requestCode when constructing my `NewPermissionRequest`.

This is what the correct `NewPermissionRequest` needs to look like :

```
        Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(
            new NewPermissionsRequest(activity, MY_PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS)
                .setRequestCode(FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE));
```